# Rails3 Autocomplete Gem - Two Different Autocompletes on Same ClassName and Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete

I am successfully using the ":scopes =>" option of this gem to return a subset of the rows of the table.  Now I want to create a nearly identical autocomplete, on the same ClassName and Method, with a different scope, for a different view.

The problem is, the first two arguments of autocomplete in the controller are ClassName and Method, and those also create the functional name of the autocomplete function, as it is used in the view and route.  Therefore, both of my autocompletes would have the same name.

Is there a workaround I can use to assign a different name to each of the similar autocompletes?

Example code:

```
autocomplete :my_class_name, :my_method, :display_value => :my_formatting_method, 
:extra_data => [:id], :scopes => [:active_and_special]

def active_and_special
    where("active = ?", true).
    where("special = ?", true).
    order("name  ASC")
end
```

Then the again for the 2nd one, with the same class-name and method, but a different scope.

Answer (score 0):

Best workaround I've found is to use "column_name" to override the part of the naming which ordinarily refers to the method - like this:

```
autocomplete :my_class_name, :foo, :column_name => 'my_method', 
  :display_value => :my_formatting_method, :extra_data => [:id], 
  :scopes => [:active_and_not_special]

def active_and_not_special
    where("active = ?", true).
    where("special = ?", false).
    order("name  ASC")
end
```

This has route:

```
get 'my_class_names/autocomplete_my_class_name_foo'
```

Whereas the original has route:

```
get 'my_class_names/autocomplete_my_class_name_my_method'
```

This allows us to generate a 2nd, different autocomplete, on the same Class and Method as another, with its own unique name.
Having an independent name, vs the 'magic' autogenerated one (to save 1 second of typing?) would prevent this trouble - or am I missing something?

I'll leave this open for a bit to see if anyone has a better solution.